# Rails 3 - validation of checkboxes

Tags: validation, model, checkbox, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I have the form 2 checkboxes and I am trying to find some way, how to validate it - I want to know, if a user clicked on one of two checkboxes...

I tried to do it with `validates_presence_of`, but unfortunately, without success...

Can anyone help me, please, how to do? Thank you, M.

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom validate functions for this.

```
 validate :custom_checkbox_validation

      def custom_checkbox_validation
        errors.add(:base, "Please check atleast one checkbox.") unless chkbox1 || chkbox2
      end
```

To work this, You should have 2 checkboxes in your view files.

```
<%= form.check_box :chkbox1 %>
<%= form.check_box :chkbox2 %>
```

Comment: yes, thank you... but I use `client_side_validation` and I am trying to edit your part of code to my model... But I don't know, how to print error message, if one of the checkboxes is not checked... For checking, if the user filled input - I am using `validates_presence_of :email, :message => "Must be filled!"`